# Do other outlook.com users find certain domains and keywords cannot be blocked via rules? e.g. support.com, email.com

Tags: outlook.com, spam-prevention, email-rules

I have been using outlook.com since forever, with a hotmail address that was migrated. I've set up a ton of rules to delete spam, and most of them seem to work fine.

But a few of them flat-out are ignored and do not work, ever. I'm curious if it's just me. I'm getting messages in my spam folder every day following the same obvious pattern, where the sender or subject line is something like viagra*cialis@email.com.

I've made rules to delete if the subject contains viagra or cialis, or if the sender's name contains those terms... none of them work. I copied and pasted straight from the email itself to ensure that there aren't some weird characters that are tricking me (i.e. the "l" isn't a "1" or something). I tried copying the full name, viagra*cialis, doesn't work.

Finally, I have rules in place to block everything from email.com, emal.com, and support.com. Yet messages slip through anyway.

Why are these domains seemingly permanently whitelisted? And why aren't the viagra and cialis rules working? Something to do with the asterisk tricking outlook's regular expression matching?

I've sent feedback on this issue a dozen times with zero replies. Been ongoing for like a year.

Comment: I don't have an answer for this, but am having exactly the same issue. Something is messed up with Outlook's rules function. Has been like that for a while.

Comment: @user98352 glad to know at least one other person in the world has noticed this... makes me want to migrate my email. It's sad that microsoft doesn't get this simple thing right, where all the other major providers do.